# Progressive web app for Chromebook in Kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, kiosk-mode, chromebook

Our requirement is to build chrome book kiosk app and the app should work offline and upload the data to cloud when the device is connected to network. Can we make progressive apps as chrome kiosk apps? Or is there any better way to approach?

Comment: AFAIK, you can use PWA in as a kiosk app. You can check this tutorial about [HOW TO IMPLEMENT PWA AND BARBA.JS INTO INTERNET KIOSKS](https://www.degordian.com/education/blog/implement-pwa-barba-js-internet-kiosks/) and it is also included in the update of I/O 2014 for Web titled ["Unleash the power of Kiosk Apps"](https://developers.google.com/web/shows/google-io/2014/unleash-the-power-of-kiosk-apps). Lastly, try checking this [GitHub](https://github.com/kyl3d3nt0n/Vados) code that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Chrome 81, you can install websites and progressive web apps (PWAs) on managed Chrome devices in locked-down kiosk mode. You can also automatically launch PWAs on a kiosk.

1. From the [Admin console Home page](https://admin.google.com), go to **Devices** > **Chrome**.
2. Click **Apps & extensions** > **Kiosks**.
3. To apply the setting to everyone, leave the top organizational unit selected. Otherwise, select a child organizational unit.
4. Click **Add** > **Add by URL**.
5. Enter the URL and click **Save**.

Full details are at [Add websites and progressive web apps to Chrome kiosks](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9781496)

Comment: I tried creating a PWA and launched it through KIOSK but it doesnt work in offline mode. It works perfectly in non kiosk offline mode. In Kiosk mode it needs to be connected to internet. Any recommendations?

Comment: Hey @Subin, I am having the exact same issue. Did you end up figuring this out?